# jQuery's removeClass or toggleClass not working in ie8? Why? How do I get it to work correctly?

Tags: jquery

The following example works fine in Firefox and Opera, but not in ie8. However, if I turn compatibility mode on in ie8, it works correctly. Why? And how do I fix it?

The below example shows the use of toggleClass, but replacing this with addClass and removeClass still has the same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .dostuff{
        background-color: green;
    }
    .undostuff{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#DoStuffButton').click(function(){doStuff();});
        $('#UndoStuffButton').click(function(){undoStuff();});

        function doStuff(){
            $('#test').html('Do some stuff');
            $('#test').toggleClass('dostuff', 'slow', callback('dostuff'));
        }

        function undoStuff(){
            $('#test').html('Undo some stuff');
            $('#test').toggleClass('undostuff', 'slow', callback('undostuff'));
        }

        function callback(className){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#test').toggleClass(className, 'slow');
            }, 1500);
        }


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Blah blah blah</div>
    <div>
        <button id="DoStuffButton" name="DoStuffButton">Do some stuff</button>
        <button id="UndoStuffButton" name="UndoStuffButton">Undo some stuff</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Changing the javascript to the following also has the same problem in ie8. Any explanation why, and how to get it to work correctly?

```
function doStuff(){
            $('#test').html('Do some stuff');
            $('#test').addClass('dostuff', 'fast');
            setTimeout(function(){$('#test').removeClass('dostuff', 'slow');}, 1000);
        }

        function undoStuff(){
            $('#test').html('Undo some stuff');
            $('#test').addClass('undostuff', 100);
            setTimeout(function(){$('#test').removeClass('undostuff', 'slow');}, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried with the latest jQuery version? (1.4.1)

Comment: Maybe something in equal `id` and `name` attributes of buttons?

Comment: just tried jQuery 1.4.1. and I still get the same result.

Comment: I tried changing the id of the buttons, still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be doing what you want it to on some browsers, but it's not doing it the way you think it is.

Firstly, your parameters to [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) don't match the API. so `'slow', callback('dostuff')` mean nothing to toggleClass.

Secondly, when you pass `callback('dostuff')` you're passing the result of **calling** that function, you're not passing a reference to the function.

Comment: if I change to to addClass and removeClass to match the API, even if I pass an anonymous function to the addClass, I get the same result. Will passing an anonymous function to addClass still be passing the result of calling that function?

Comment: @Jayson, neither addClass, removeClass or toggleClass accept a callback function as a parameter. It only works in your example because `callback('dostuff')` is called **straight away** when it is passed and you're actually passing in undefined as the callback function doesn't return anything.

Comment: you right, the API doesn't specify a callback. My mistake was I was following the example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/. However, even if I do the following, it still doesn't work in IE8. Any explanation for this?
function doStuff(){
   $('#test').html('Do some stuff');
   $('#test').addClass('dostuff', 'fast');
   setTimeout(function(){$('#test').removeClass('dostuff', 'slow');}, 1000);
  }

Comment: @Jayson 'fast' and 'slow' are invalid parameters. And it works for me in IE8: http://jsbin.com/evivu

Comment: invalid parameters are in the example jqueryui.com/demos/addClass. Removing the parameters solves the problem.